# MYSQL Procedure not getting called

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

The Following procedure after getting called, shows up error "The Result return more than one row" where the input value given is just one parameter.

```
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE p( IN en int,OUT ename int, OUT incr_sal int, OUT s_sal 
    int, OUT count1 int)
    BEGIN

    DECLARE sal INT DEFAULT 0; 
    DECLARE cnt int DEFAULT 0; 
    DECLARE emp_name int DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT `ename`,`salary` INTO sal, emp_name 
    FROM works w 
    WHERE `ename`=en;

    SELECT COUNT(m.empname) INTO cnt 
    FROM manages m 
    WHERE m.empname=en 
    GROUP BY m.empname;

    SET @ename=emp_name; SET @incr_sal=sal;

    IF sal>50000 && cnt>2 THEN SET sal=sal+((sal*5)/100);
       ELSEIF sal>50000 && sal<60000 && cnt>=1 THEN SET sal=sal+((sal*2)/100);
       ELSEIF sal>10000 && cnt=0 THEN SET sal=sal+((sal*1)/100);
    end IF;

    SET @s_sal=sal; 
    SET @count1=cnt;

    SELECT @ename,@incr_sal,@s_sal,@count1;
    END $$
    DELIMITER ;

    CALL p('Sam',@ename,@incr_sal,@s_sal,@cnt);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute query seperately and see the result

```
SELECT `ename`,`salary` INTO sal, emp_name 
FROM works w 
WHERE `ename`=en;
```

Are you expected more than one row here or just one. If expecting one then just add limit 1 to query as :

```
 SELECT `ename`,`salary` INTO sal, emp_name 
FROM works w 
WHERE `ename`=en limit 1;
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer.  I did try this. But i am getting the same error saying SQL query:


CALL p('Sam',@ename,@incr_sal,@s_sal,@cnt)
MySQL said: Documentation

#1172 - Result consisted of more than one row

Comment: just to know the input parameter is " IN en INT" , "OUT ename INT" , "OUT incr_sal INT", "OUT s_sal INT" , "OUT count1 INT" . I did not use VARCHAR for 'en' because any the procedure which I am using doesn't work with VARCHAR only INT and BLOB.

Comment: Ok so now its working or not. But you have mentioned the error was  'The Result return more than one row' . If you were doing above mistake then then error would be 'Error Code: 1366. Incorrect integer value: 'Sam' for column 'en' at row 1.'

Comment: Is there any reason your procedure not working with varchar . What error your getting on use. Is it a syntax error.